# Verify the existence of a message by its ID

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I would like to verify the existence of a message by its ID.

The code here works, but if the message doesn't exist, it doesn't tell me "undefined".

```
let channel = bot.channels.cache.get("846857716290813962");
const message = channel.messages.fetch("847383565220970497");
```

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Unknown Message

Comment: Try checking `!message`

Answer (score 0):

You can just handle the errors that come in a try/catch block.

The following function should check if a message exists by ID, and if there are any errors, it will catch the error, console.log() it, and return false.

```
const checkIfMessageExists = async (channelId, messageId) => {
    try {
        let channel = bot.channels.cache.get(channelId);
        const message = await channel.messages.fetch(messageId);
        if (message) return true;
    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error.message)
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: The problem is the same :(

Comment: What exactly happens, and what is it that you'd like to happen?

Comment: I put a false message and it doesn't work, the same error "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Unknown Message" ;'(

Comment: Yeah, if the message doesn't exist, you'll still get the same error.  However, the function should return false now.

Comment: console.log(checkIfMessageExists()) I do that but return the same error, you function doesn't work ?

Comment: Well, I made sure to console.log() the error in the catch block of the try/catch, so you'd still see the error in the console.  Does it only show the error?  It should also show true or false as well.

Comment: It's working but Promise { <pending> } false ;( I want just "false"

Comment: Yeah, just take a look at the edit I made to my answer.  I wasn't so familiar with discord.js, but apparently, the "fetch" function is asynchronous.  Just add the async/await keywords where I added them, and you should be fine.